# Two issue in my java code, incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int and boolean cannot be converted to int

Tags: java

```
public class Applicants {
    //data fields
    private String name; //to hold the name
    private int[] academicData; //to hold the grades from 6 core CS courses

    //constructors
    public Applicants(){
        //default constructor
    }
    public Applicants(String name, int[] academicData){
        setName(name);
        setAcademicData(academicData);
    }
    public Applicants(String name){
        setName(name);
    }

    //getters and setters
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int[] getAcademicData(){
        return academicData;
    }
    public void setAcademicData(int[] academicData){
        this.academicData = academicData;
    }

    //methods to analyze applications
    public boolean averageAbove85(){
        int sum = 0;
        for (int grade : academicData){
            sum += grade;
        }
        double average = sum / academicData.length;
        return average > 85;
    }
    public boolean noGradeBelow65(){
        for (int grade : academicData){
            if (grade < 65){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    public boolean atleastFour85(){
        int count = 0;
        for (int grade : academicData){
            if (grade > 85){
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count >= 4;
    }
    public boolean upperLevelAbove85(){
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = academicData.length - 4; i < academicData.length; i++){
            sum += academicData[i];
        }
        double average = sum / 4;
        return average > 85;
    }
    public boolean customFilter(int[] data){
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            if (i < 6){
                sum += data[i];
            }
            else if (i >=6 && data[i] > 3.5){
                count++;
            }
        }
        double average = sum / 6;
        return (average > 70 && count > 0);
    }

}
```

```
public class TestApplicants {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Applicants applicant1 = new Applicants("John Doe", new int[]{90, 95, 80, 100, 75, 95});
        System.out.println(applicant1.averageAbove85()); //true
        System.out.println(applicant1.noGradeBelow65()); //true
        System.out.println(applicant1.atleastFour85()); //false
        System.out.println(applicant1.upperLevelAbove85()); //true
        System.out.println(applicant1.customFilter(new int[]{90, 95, 80, 100, 75, 95, 4.0, true, 3})); //true

        Applicants applicant2 = new Applicants("Jane Doe", new int[]{60, 70, 80, 85, 95, 100});
        System.out.println(applicant2.averageAbove85()); //true
        System.out.println(applicant2.noGradeBelow65()); //false
        System.out.println(applicant2.atleastFour85()); //true
        System.out.println(applicant2.upperLevelAbove85()); //true
        System.out.println(applicant2.customFilter(new int[]{60, 70, 80, 85, 95, 100, 3.2, false, 1})); //false
    }
}
```

help! with fixing these two issues (incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to int and possible lossy conversion from double to int), i tried replacing int with double but that didn't work, and i was thinking maybe boolean is the issue here but if someone can please take a look. these are two java files one is  Applicants and the other TestApplicants that work hand in hand!

Comment: where exactly are those errors? I can see that `customFilter(int[] data)` doesn't take any booleans and you try to put one as an arugment in there for some reason unclear to me. Oh and doubles  too. Why? What's the purpose of them? `new int[]{60, 70, 80, 85, 95, 100, >> 3.2, >> false, 1}`

Comment: `int[]` is an array of integers. What's the integer value of `true`? If you were at the supermarket and bought `true` eggs, how many egg sandwiches could you make from them? Similarly, 3.2 is not an integer. It's hard to know what you're trying to do, so we can't really suggest a fix; but your `int[]` has to only contain ints.